# How to replace next Character of string with immediate character

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to replace next character of string with immediate character.
For example, 
given string is 
`"HOME"`

required string should be 
`"EHOM"`,

Is it possible to do it without any replace function.

Comment: C# or vb.net? Why both tags?
And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you tried replacing using For loop?

Comment: String is immutable, so you need to create a new string with for loop taking elements in order you want.

Comment: Due to immutability of strings, you can create another string instance and use `Substring` method to take last characters and put them on initial position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like just moving the last character in front:

```
string s = "HOME";
s = s.Last() + s.Remove(s.Length - 1);   // "EHOM"
```

Answer (score 1):

approach "doing everything on foot":

make a char array as long as your string ... (no trailing null)

have a for loop with the index i go through the array

calculate the replacement position r = i - 1 + len(array) mod len(array)

fetch char from position r in the original string

put fetched char at position i of your array

end of loop

make a string from your array

Answer (score 1):

Basic string functions:

```
    string x = "Home";
    string y = x.Substring(x.Length - 1, 1) + x.Substring(0, x.Length - 1);
```

Please note that you should declare a new string to respect immutability.